# Why Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item::getRemoveUrl() is escaped and getUrl() is not?

Tags: layered-navigation

There are two methods in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item`. One retrieves the URL of for a filter:

```
public function getUrl()
{
    $query = array(
        $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
        Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
    );
    return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
}
```

and another removes it:

```
public function getRemoveUrl()
{
    $query = array($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getFilter()->getResetValue());
    $params['_current']     = true;
    $params['_use_rewrite'] = true;
    $params['_query']       = $query;
    $params['_escape']      = true;
    return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', $params);
}
```

I'm wondering is there any reason why an URL for `getRemoveUrl` is escaped and `getUrl` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `getUrl` is escaped in the template.
Check `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml`.
the filter URL is rendered like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
```

`urlEscape` is a wrapper for `htmlspecialchars`.

In `state.phtml` (same folder) the remove url is rendered like so `href="<?php echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>"`.

I couldn't tell you the reason. All I know is that in both cases the url's get escaped. At least in the default theme.